# SQL Server Management Studio won't recognize a tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image]

This happens frequently to me, SQL Server doesn't recognize my tables.

I tried to refresh the database, also tried to refresh the intellisense. But nothing worked!

Could anyone help please?

Comment: And what is the [current database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180770(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_2) for that tab?

Comment: I only have one database which is Sales_DB

Comment: No, you most certainly have [other databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/system-databases) as well.

Comment: Oh, Thank you. i have to select the database before creating a query.

Comment: Your word 'Tab' helped me figure it out. Thanks @GSerg

Comment: Can you ensure that you are not running this against the "master" database? When setting up a user, if a default database is not specified, when you connect using SSMS it defaults to master.. change the db or use the use[your database] statement before you run any other queries.

Comment: Could you write `USE Sales_DB` above your select query and try again?

Comment: Yes this was my problem, I didn't know that I have to specify the database first. Thank you @Harry

Comment: Sweet.. can you accept this as an answer below then please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you ensure that you are not running this against the "master" database? When setting up a user, if a default database is not specified, when you connect using SSMS it defaults to master.. change the db or use the use[your database] statement before you run any other queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can preface the code with

```
USE Sales_DB
```

And it will always start with that database.